# Training GAN model : UnboundLocalError: local variable 'text' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

After compiling this :

```
train(subTrainLoader)
file.close()
```

The error I get says: :

```
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-2586b0a98598> in <module>()
----> 1 train(subTrainLoader)
      2 file.close()

<ipython-input-20-de0a01f87708> in train(datasetLoader)
      1 global test
      2 def train(datasetLoader):
----> 3   file.write(text)
      4   for epoch in range(epochs):
      5     netC.train()

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'text' referenced before assignment.
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I think there is some typo in the `global text` variable plz correct it

Comment: thank you, but after changing it I came with another issue, this is a new issue with PyTorch and how they use cross entropy. 
ValueError: Using a target size (torch.Size([64, 1])) that is different to the input size (torch.Size([64])) is deprecated. Please ensure they have the same size.